# Migrating from Drupal 7: source database does not contain a recognizable Drupal version

Tags: database, 8, migrations

After looking at [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2637870), it appears to be my schema_version. How and what do I need to change about the [table](https://i.imgur.com/UJuELaD.png) to get it [recognizable as a Drupal version?](https://i.imgur.com/hC1Y5nN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this after putting in the correct prefix.  This issue on drupal.org was very helpful: https://www.drupal.org/node/2637870

The correct prefix for anyone with a similar problem is shown here: [http://i.imgur.com/MKf6CuG.png](https://i.imgur.com/MKf6CuG.png)